# Enyime Couchbase - flushing memcached bucket

Tags: c#, memcached, couchbase, enyim, enyim.caching

I'm trying to flush a memcached bucket in Couchbase using the Enyim client library.

```
using (var client = new MemcachedClient())
        {                                
            client.FlushAll();                
        }
```

This doesn't work as my next request is **still** returning data from the cache.

This does work if i explicity call remove as below

```
using (var client = new MemcachedClient())
        {                
            client.Remove(key);
        }
```

But I want a way to invalidate all of the items in the bucket as they will be invalidated by an external data load.

NB. Initiating a flush on the bucket from the Couchbase admin web app does have the desired outcome.

Why does it not work in Enyim?

Comment: What version of the client are you using? Have you considered updating to the latest Couchbase SDK? https://www.nuget.org/packages/CouchbaseNetClient/

Comment: Yes that is what we have now done. Originally I thought Enyim was faster than the Couchbase SDK but I was not using the ClusterHelper which made a big difference.